# how to divide boost::optional<double>?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I have such code:

```
boost::optional<double> result = _ind1.Value() / _ind2.Value();
```

Each arg is `boost::optional<double>` too:

```
boost::optional<double> Value() {
    return value;
}
```

Errors are:

`Error  1   error C2676: binary '/' : 'boost::optional<T>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
    2   IntelliSense: no operator "/" matches these operands
            operand types are: boost::optional<double> / boost::optional<double>`

I understand that it seems that division is just not defined. I expect result to be `boost::none` if any of two arguments is `none` - otherwise I want it to be normal double division. Should I just write this myself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course such a simple operation as division of doubles is supported.

But you aren't trying to divide doubles. You're trying to divide `boost::optional<double>`s which is a whole different story.

If you want, you can define a division operator for this. It might look like (untested):

```
template<typename T>
boost::optional<T> operator/(const boost::optional<T>& a, const boost::optional<T>& b)
{
    if(a && b) return *a / *b;
    else return boost::optional<T>();
}
```

In C++11 (code courtesy of Yakk):

```
template<class T,class U> struct divide_result {
  typedef typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>()/std::declval<U>())>::type;
};
template<class T, class U> using divide_result_t=typename divide_result<T,U>::type;
template<typename T,typename U>
boost::optional<divide_result_t<T,U>> operator/(const boost::optional<T>& a, const boost::optional<U>& b)
{
    if(a && b) return *a / *b;
    else return boost::none;
}
```

I used a template because now it's also good for int, float, etc.

Comment: Do you need to convert the return value to a `boost::optional<double>`? or is there an implicit conversion?

Comment: @Ferruccio: It has an implicit conversion.

Comment: what, no `T`/`U` support with automatic promotion?

Comment: @Yakk: You can write the upgraded version. :-)

Comment: @zanlynx sure, make me write code on my phone.  You can add SFINAE support if you want.

Comment: Overall it looks quite complicated. Now i think probably it would be easier less error phrone and faster just use "double + bool" fields and do the rest myself?

Comment: @javapowered: My version isn't that complicated. You'd only need the C++11 version by Yakk for dividing more complicated things, like a double by a complex or something like that.

Comment: @javapowered: or just take the if statement out of the above code and use it directly.

Comment: The C++11 version supports `optional<A>/optional<B>` where the types do not match (ie, one is `int` and another `double`